# Поделиться текстом с HTML тегами

Tags: java, android, html

Приветствую. У меня приложение получает текст из БД, текст в БД обработан `HTML` тегами, я реализовал кнопку `Share` и прописал в методе `onClick` следующий код:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       i.setType("text/html");
       i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(RU_TEXT));
       i = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.action_share));
       startActivity(i);
```

Теперь, когда я делюсь текстом, список доступных приложений мал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя у меня установлен `Whatsapp` и прочие приложения поддерживающие текстовую рассылку, я так полагаю их нет в списке по причине того, что в них не поддерживаются `html` теги? Возможно ли как-то решить эту проблему, и сделать так, чтобы отображались все приложения которые поддерживают текстовую рассылку?

Comment: Какой смысл посылать html в приложения, которые не поддерживают html? Даже если это сделать, чуда не произойдёт и они не начнут его поддерживать. Сделайте `Html.fromHtml(RU_TEXT).toString()` либо просто отправляйте `RU_TEXT`.

Comment: Если я сделаю RU_TEXT просто, то текст будет передаваться с тегами. И у меня не стоит задача посылать текст с `html` тегами в приложения которые это не поддерживают, я задал вопрос чтобы решить как-то эту проблему, если она решается

Comment: Ну то есть вы хотите просто поделиться текстом без html тегов? Тогда используйте первый вариант, который я предложил. Просто добавьте `.toString()`.

Comment: В общем если просто с `.toString()` то не работает, а если в варианте как указал @Evgen Orlovsky, с `text/*` то работает. Так что не знаю кого и как отметить правильным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте заменить установку типа в вашем коде на следующий:

```
shareIntent.setType("text/*");
```

чтобы из html выбрать текст для отправки (без тегов), как выше указал `eugeneek`:

```
Html.fromHtml(RU_TEXT).toString()
```

Comment: Теперь появились все приложения, однако текст в них не отправляется, осталось найти способ чтобы теги в тех приложениях где они не поддерживаются как-то игнорировались, и обрезались.

Comment: @McDaggen а вариант вытягивания текста из html предложенный `eugeneek` в комментариях сразу под вашим вопросом не работает? или работает не так как надо?

Comment: работает только если ваш ответ и первый ответ совместить, одно без другого не работает. Так что не знаю как отметить правильный ответ

Comment: дополнил ответ, только учтите что если вы будете выбирать текст из html - там где была возможность разметки по тегам - ее уже не будет.